# MvvmCross : conventional plugin bypass

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I get this error when I use `AddConventionalPlugin`:

You must pass in the type of a plugin instance - like

```
typeof(Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.WindowsPhone.Plugin)
```

because my plugin is something like:

```
Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wp7.Plugin
```

I think Wp7 and Wp8 will be splitted in 2 projects because they will use a different SDK.

Is there a way to bypass this problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'convention' part is simply the naming convention.

i.e. it's just looking for something that will provide an IMvxPlugin for:

```
 Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility
```

using the rule 'add "WindowsPhone"' to get:

```
 Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.WindowsPhone.Plugin
```

If the rule changes for WP8... then we can just change the convention in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone/Platform/MvxBaseWindowsPhoneSetup.cs

---

While WP8 is still a bit unclear... You can do this yourself in your project in your Setup.cs using code like:

```
    protected override IMvxPluginManager CreatePluginManager()
    {
        var toReturn = new MvxLoaderBasedPluginManager();
        var registry = new MvxLoaderPluginRegistry(".WP7",toReturn.Loaders);
        AddPluginsLoaders(registry);
        return toReturn;
    }
```

or you could even mix and match versions - i.e. you could do something like:

```
    protected override IMvxPluginManager CreatePluginManager()
    {
        var toReturn = new MvxLoaderBasedPluginManager();

        var sharedRegistry = new MvxLoaderPluginRegistry(".WindowsPhone",toReturn.Loaders);
        sharedRegistry.AddConventionBasedPlugin<SharedP1>();
        sharedRegistry.AddConventionBasedPlugin<SharedP1>();
        sharedRegistry.AddConventionBasedPlugin<SharedP3>();

        var wp7Registry = new MvxLoaderPluginRegistry(".WP7",toReturn.Loaders);
        wp7Registry.AddConventionBasedPlugin<WP7P1>();
        wp7Registry.AddConventionBasedPlugin<WP7P2>();

        return toReturn;
    }
```

---

Finally, there's nothing forcing you to use conventions at all - you can always just provide your own plugin loading methods providing `Func<IMvxPlugin>` - e.g.

```
    protected override IMvxPluginManager CreatePluginManager()
    {
        var toReturn = new MvxLoaderBasedPluginManager();

        toReturn.Loaders.Add('Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.WindowsPhone.Plugin', () =>
               {
                  // do whatever code you want to do...
                  return thePlugin; 
               });

        return toReturn;
    }
```

You can mix and match these techniques

---

Alternatively, you can provide a totally new implementation of IMvxPluginManager if you want to. The interface is just:

```
public interface IMvxPluginManager
{
    bool IsPluginLoaded<T>() where T : IMvxPluginLoader;
    void EnsureLoaded<T>() where T : IMvxPluginLoader;
}
```

So, you could, for example provide a very simply manager like

```
public class SimplePluginManager : IMvxPluginManager
{
    public SimplePluginManager()
    {
        // load the plugins your app needs here!
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Wp7.Plugin.Load();
        Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.WindowsPhone.Plugin.Load();
    }

    public bool IsPluginLoaded<T>() where T : IMvxPluginLoader
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void EnsureLoaded<T>() where T : IMvxPluginLoader
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be solved as I get a new error. I will dig to find a solution. Thank you for your quick help.