# MvvmCross Plugin convention for Xamarin.Mac

Tags: macos, plugins, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.mac

I would like to add a Xamarin.Mac implementation to our MvvmCross plugins.

In the wiki ([wiki link](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins)) it lists the platform naming conventions as:

- Android: Acme.Vibrate.Droid.dll
- iOS: Acme.Vibrate.Touch.dll
- WindowsPhone: Acme.Vibrate.WindowsPhone.dll
- WindowsStore: Acme.Vibrate.WindowsStore.dll
- Wpf: Acme.Vibrate.Wpf.dll

Is Xamarin.Mac supported and if so, what is the convention?

If not, is it best to wire it up as descibed in [MvvmCross : conventional plugin bypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842727/mvvmcross-conventional-plugin-bypass)

Thanks.

Comment: I should have first looked into the MvvmCross source.  I just did and found this code in the Setup.cs in MvvmCross.Mac.Platform: 'var registry = new MvxLoaderPluginRegistry(".Mac", toReturn.Loaders);'
Just to confirm, the plugin convention is (no surprise) .Mac?

Comment: It is going to be '.Mac' but currently no official '.Mac' platform is available. At least one user is using mvvmcross on 'Xamarin.Mac' but this isn't yet fully publicly published.

Comment: @Stuart thanks for the update.  I would like to start porting some of the MvvmCross Wpf, Droid, and Touch to Mac.  Even if it is in beta, is there anything I can start with now?  Thanks.

Comment: @Stuart Also, can you point me to starter template code for an MvvmCross MonoMac/Xamarin.Mac project.  I have some of the setup, binding, etc working for a Mac project but not all.  Again thanks.

Comment: Try commenting on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/pull/126 - others who are working on it may help there

Comment: @Stuart do you know when MonoMac / Xamarin.Mac support will be release (even in beta form)?